# Navbar that adds and removes classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written some jQuery for my navbar, but it's super sloppy and I'm always trying to write better code.

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
    var sT = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (sT >= 70) {
        $('.navbar').addClass('navbar-switch')
        $('.navbar .scroll-link').addClass('navbar-link-switch')
        $('.navbar .logo').addClass('logo-adjust')
        $('.navbar hr').addClass('hide')
        $('.navbar .navbar-collapse').addClass('border')
    } else {            
        $('.navbar').removeClass('navbar-switch')
        $('.navbar .scroll-link').removeClass('navbar-link-switch')
        $('.navbar .logo').removeClass('logo-adjust')
        $('.navbar hr').removeClass('hide')
        $('.navbar .navbar-collapse').removeClass('border')
    }
    })
})
```

My goal is that, when the user scrolls pass a certain limit, my navbar removes certain classes and adds certain classes.

Comment: What you could do is add only ONE class, say "switch", just to the main navbar. Then act on elements differently, whether they belong to "navbar" or to "navbar.switch". You can, for instance, have `navbar button { background : blue }` and `navbar.switch button { background : green }`. The color of the button will change depending on scrollTop value.

Comment: Any chance you can share your HTML too? Do you have control over your HTML? Might be easier to use Bootstrap's built-in ability to toggle.

Answer (score 1):

Is hard to evaluate without the html  but, considere introduce `toggleClass`.

```
$element.toggleClass(className, condition);
```

http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

If your jQuery version doesn´t allow it, you can introduce as a separate function:

```
function toggleClass($element, class, condition) {
   condition ? $element.addClass(class) : $element.removeClass(class);
}
```

and the full solution: http://jsfiddle.net/cbhvteon/1/